# R Studio Cast/Melt on a data.frame

Tags: r, reshape2

I have been trying different methods to achieve this and I am failing.  I feel this is simple and I am not sure what I am missing...I am trying to convert this data frame below:

[image]

into

[image]

I gather I need to melt first, then cast, although I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
mydata <- melt(df, id.vars = "Company", measure.vars = "Product")
mydata2 <- cast(mydata, "Company" ~ "Product")
```

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way to do this in base r would be to transpose each company's sales in a loop and convert back to a data.frame.

```
lst = list()
i <- 1
for (name in unique(df$Company)){
  lst[[i]] <- data.frame(t(df[df$Company == name, 'Sales']))
  i <- i + 1
}

out <- cbind(unique(df$Company), Reduce(rbind, lst))
colnames(out) <- c(colnames(df)[1], unique(df$Product))
out
```

**Edit:** Here's a function that wraps the previous answer.

```
convwide <- function(data, by, datcol, namcol){
    lst = list()
    i <- 1
    for (name in unique(df[[by]])){
      lst[[i]] <- data.frame(t(df[df[[by]] == name, datcol]))
      i <- i + 1
    }

    out <- cbind(unique(df[[by]]), Reduce(rbind, lst))
    colnames(out) <- c(by, unique(df[[namcol]]))
   return(out)
    }
convwide(df, 'Company', 'Sales', 'Product')
```